# Website Marked as Phising by Edge

Tags: phishing, joomla, microsoft-edge

I handle a joomla website (https://dom-ng.eu) which is marked as unsafe by Microsoft Edge but not Chrome an others. The site is flagged with a phishing threat and i tried to fix the issue but it's not working out. Now i don't know what content that cause it to happen. I added it to Bing webmaster and got links inside this [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Q1dBSlpqhcoGuiHGsbGZcvuc0Kcd4AZX). Any ideas what is the cause?

Comment: Not sure what the cause is, but when I try to access it with chrome, I'm also met with a phishing warning (I use McAfee Internet Security)

Comment: @shaan now you mention it, i remembered McAfee Internet Security also marked this site as phising. i hate it when they give no details

Comment: Do not repost closed questions

Comment: @schroeder sorry, cause i couldn't find that question before i repost this one